# How to copy the sentence after changing a word?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a simple batch code that can change the read out from my android phone.
But my problem is how to copy all the sentence that I have changed in other `.txt` file.

Read out from my phone:

> ```
> ----ia-A--- /xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx
> ```

Output using my code:

> ```
> -iaA /xxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx
> ```

How can I copy all this sentence to other `.txt` file not including the readout that has not changed?
I just want to copy all the sentence that I have changed.

I am using this code:

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (virus_attribute2.txt) do (
set attrib=%%A
set attrib=!attrib:-----ia-A----=-iaA! 
echo !attrib!>>attrib1.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for my interpretation of your question:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
(FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('FIND "-----ia-A----"^<"virus_attribute2.txt"') DO (
    SET matchline=%%A
    CALL ECHO=%%matchline:-----ia-A----=-iaA%%))>attrib1.txt
```

Comment: you'll have to escape the `<`

Comment: wow success thank you sir Compo for your code...now i can make a virus scanner for my tool...